# Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server

Tags: ssh, apt

I have Debian Testing on my server. When do upgrade, it wants to upgrade openssh-server and fails...

```
openssh-server (1:7.3p1-1) wird eingerichtet ...
Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript ssh, action "start" failed.
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mo 2016-08-22 11:40:09 CEST; 13ms ago
  Process: 32634 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 32634 (code=exited, status=255)

Aug 22 11:40:09 elserver systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Aug 22 11:40:09 elserver systemd[1]: ssh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Aug 22 11:40:09 elserver systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Aug 22 11:40:09 elserver systemd[1]: ssh.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 22 11:40:09 elserver systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes openssh-server (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 openssh-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I do *systemctl status ssh.service* or *journalctl -xe* as suggested or *service ssh status* I get the very same message. I am afraid now to restart the machine, because I am in fact connected via ssh and am afraid now that I won't be able to reconnect after reboot.
I also tried to reinstall openssh-server anyway wich didn't change anything.

Any suggestions what might be the problem here?

---

Edit 1
This is the output of *sshd -T*:

```
port 22
protocol 2
addressfamily any
listenaddress [::]:22
listenaddress 0.0.0.0:22
usepam yes
serverkeybits 1024
logingracetime 120
keyregenerationinterval 3600
x11displayoffset 10
maxauthtries 6
maxsessions 10
clientaliveinterval 0
clientalivecountmax 3
streamlocalbindmask 0177
permitrootlogin without-password
ignorerhosts yes
ignoreuserknownhosts no
rhostsrsaauthentication no
hostbasedauthentication no
hostbasedusesnamefrompacketonly no
rsaauthentication yes
pubkeyauthentication yes
kerberosauthentication no
kerberosorlocalpasswd yes
kerberosticketcleanup yes
gssapiauthentication no
gssapikeyexchange no
gssapicleanupcredentials yes
gssapistrictacceptorcheck yes
gssapistorecredentialsonrekey no
passwordauthentication yes
kbdinteractiveauthentication no
challengeresponseauthentication no
printmotd no
printlastlog yes
x11forwarding yes
x11uselocalhost yes
permittty yes
permituserrc yes
strictmodes yes
tcpkeepalive yes
permitemptypasswords no
permituserenvironment no
uselogin no
compression delayed
gatewayports no
usedns no
allowtcpforwarding yes
allowagentforwarding yes
allowstreamlocalforwarding yes
streamlocalbindunlink no
useprivilegeseparation yes
fingerprinthash SHA256
pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid
xauthlocation /usr/bin/xauth
ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
macs umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
versionaddendum none
kexalgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
hostbasedacceptedkeytypes ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
hostkeyalgorithms ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
pubkeyacceptedkeytypes ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
loglevel INFO
syslogfacility AUTH
authorizedkeysfile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
acceptenv LANG
acceptenv LC_*
authenticationmethods any
subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
maxstartups 10:30:100
permittunnel no
ipqos lowdelay throughput
rekeylimit 0 0
permitopen any
```

Comment: Run the `sudo sshd -T` (ssh test mode). It will tell you what is wrong with the configuration, which is most probably the problem.

Comment: I did and pasted the output above because I can not find any problem there.

Comment: `I have Debian Testing on my server.` This makes this [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: The config is ok. Then there is some problem in runtime: `sudo sshd -Dddd` should trigger that error.